# Kickstart: one network card with DHCP, one with static IP?

Tags: networking, centos, ip, kickstart

I am using Kickstart to automate a CentOS install. I wanted one of the interfaces to have static IP so I wrote -

```
network --onboot yes --bootproto static \
        -ip="intended IP" -netmask="intended netmask" \
        -gateway="intented gateway" --device eth0*
```

I also wanted the other ethernet to have dynamic ip so i also configured a DHCP server for my network and for the other interface card wrote

```
network --onboot yes --device eth1 --bootproto dhcp
```

But to my surprise the ethernet to be configured static was also provided with dynamic IP. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems simple. You used the wrong syntax. "-" instead of "--".

Comment: No Nils I checked via **`ksconfig`** program  too

Comment: @mandeep that would not be the first GUI to generate a wrong configuration. I checked the CentOS-kickstart-documentation for the syntax.